# How far can a 3+1 CCTV cable carry video effectively?

Tags: cctv

I'm scouting to setup a home surveillance system for the grounds.
The grounds are overgrown with shrubbery, ivy, and trees. The former two I shall address; the last I can not.
The best location I can come up with for cameras is atop a 20' 2"x1" Mild Steel angle (nominally 18' as 3' will go into the foundation). The distance in a straight line to the boundaries of interest are around 60', 100'.

My concern though is running CCTV 3+1 cables from this pole to the house which is around 50' from the pole (68' from the camera) where the DVR will be. I can probably mount the power-supply in a weatherproof box on the pole itself but the video-out will have to reach the main structure which is quite some distance i.e. 88' or better.

How far can a 3+1 CCTV cable carry video effectively ?

Comment: Why are you doing anything but Ethernet + PoE for video surveillance today? Ethernet can handle up to 100m, and in practice even a bit more.

Comment: Got the data on the cable for attenuation in dB/km? also +1 for ethernet

Comment: Another +  for Ethernet getting a modern setup will be much better in the long run 300’ is a no problem I have run 300v cat V with power for close to the entire run and had no issues with high res cameras.

Comment: The thing with ethernet is ... utter novice here- I reckon ethernet means IP Camera. That pushes the costs up enormously

Answer (score 1):

Quite a bit further than 88', if the cable is decent. CCTV is baseband video (below 6MHz) rather than RF, so the loss of ordinary RG-59 is less than 1db per 100 feet.